# Update cart quantity without reload the page in shopify

Tags: shopify

I made that: if you click the cart button it won’t open when it’s empty. But there is a problem if you add an item to the cart it won’t open it until you update the page, This means that the quantity is not updated until you update the page, I would like to solve this problem without having to refresh the page. I'm using Dawn theme, for make the cart open only when something inside i added this {% if cart.item_count > 0 %} in header.liquid. So i think i need to update this cart.item_count

i want to open the cart only when something inside.

Comment: Check this https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart